# If $z=x+iy$, then $|\cos z|\ge |\cos x|$ and $|\sin z|\ge \sin x$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I'm trying to use that

$$|\cos z| = \left|\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})\right| = \left|\frac{1}{2}(\cos z+i\sin z + \cos -z + i\sin -z)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{2}(2\cos z)\right|$$

but I return to the same thing. Also, I couldn't understand this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698765/prove-that-sin-z-geq-sin-x-and-cos-z-geq-cos-x)'s answers, specially in why

$$\sin^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\cos^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
\ge \sin^2(x)
$$

Comment: Because $\cosh^2-1 = \sinh^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write$$
\begin{align}
|\cos(z)|^2&=|\cos(x)\cosh(y)+i\sin(x)\sinh(y)|^2\\
&=\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
&=\cos^2(x)\cosh^2(y)+(1-\cos^2(x))\sinh^2(y)\\
&=\cos^2(x)(\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y))+\sinh^2(y)\\
&=\cos^2(x)\cdot 1+\sinh^2(y)\\
&\ge \cos^2(x),
\end{align}
$$ and similarly for $|\sin(z)|^2$.